# Prestashop backoffice started loading very slow

Tags: symfony, prestashop

today my prestashop back office started loading really slow.
The information page in advanced parameters isn't even loading. It keeps trying to load and after a time it just timesout.

I enabled debug mode and noticed that TraceableFirewallListener takes a really long time to finish.

I disabled the api calls in class/tools.php but that did nothing to help.

```
    public static function addonsRequest($request, $params = array())
    {
        return false;
```

My prestashop version is 1.7.6.5

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that on 1.7 there's a second call to Addons API in `src/Adapter/Addons/AddonsDataProvider.php` you might want to disable it here as well.

Overall it would be extremely hard to help you without debugging your store directly